# How do I rename a file in GitLab in the web browser?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm currently away from my computer and I'm wondering if there's any way of renaming a file in my Gitlab repo. I tried using the web IDE but all it would do is create an empty file name with the file I wanted to rename?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

For me, I have a drop-down menu for each file:

[image: rename a file in web IDE]

Is this not an option in your (version of the) web IDE?

Gitlab references:

- Gitlab forum: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/delete-rename-a-file-folder/18304
- Gitlab's own MR of the feature, with documentation: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/merge_requests/20835

Comment: I was looking for way to do this in the regular web interface, but yes opening the web IDE makes it pretty simple to change file names. Thanks!